# c++ beginner segmentation fault when using strings

Tags: c++, string, class, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to set up a basic class using std::string as a function type and a variable type, but using both gives me a segmentation fault. If I delete either the function or the variable, everything is fine. I'm sure I'm making a really stupid mistake! This is my code:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "myclass.h"

int main()
{

    myclass obj;
    obj.replace();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H_
#define MYCLASS_H_
#include <string>

class myclass
{
    private:
        std::string instruction;

    public:
        myclass();
        std::string replace();
}; 

#endif
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <iostream>


myclass::myclass()
{
    std::cout<<"I am the constructor"<<std::endl;
}

std::string myclass::replace()
{
    std::cout<<"I replace"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: For starters, you said you'd return an `std::string` from `myclass::replace` and you didn't, so that's an issue.

Comment: I am impressed you even reach a seg fault. Compiler should at least warn you if not return an error.

Comment: Added a return statement in and tada! Thanks very much faranwath

Comment: @faranwath Add you answer, you'll get upvote on it instead of your comment.

Comment: @EricFortin: Sadly, some popular compilers don't give warnings (let alone reject code with warnings) unless you tell them to.

Comment: @MikeSeymour GCC being one of them :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `myclass::replace` was to return an `std::string` every time it gets called, but you didn't actually `return`ed anything! What happened then enters the realm of undefined behavior, which usually means your program will misbehave and eventually could even [kill your cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/undefined-behavior-killed-my-cat).

The solution is to add a `return` statement at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
obj.replace();
```

you have discarded return value, `std::string`
You can discard the return value. It's no good style in general, but you can always do it. But the actual problem is that you don't return anything from `replace` function:

```
std::string myclass::replace()
{
    std::cout<<"I replace"<<std::endl;
    //... return statement is missing
}
```

solution:

```
std::string myclass::replace()
{
    std::cout<<"I replace"<<std::endl;
    return std::string();
}
```